# What is the best ZFS configuration for logging purposes?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, zfs

I am planning for hardware that will be used for log management purposes. The software we plan to run on top of the hardware supports tiering and the plan is to go with three tiers as follows:

1. tier will be SSD, will be built from disk directly attached to the server chassis, and will be used for the first 7 days of data
2. tier will be spinning disks, will be built from disks directly attached to the server chassis, and will be used for the first 180-7 day of data.
3. tier will be spinning disks, will be built from disks located on a separate SAS direct-attached storage.

The underlying OS is Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 and unfortunately I cannot affect this decision.

The server chassis we are planning to use is Dell R740xd and its layout would be as follows:

- 2 x 300 GB 15K SAS HDD
- 2 x 1.6 TB SAS SSD
- 18 x 2.4 TB 10K SAS HDD

For the OS and the application I plan to use a zpool that consists of one mirror vdev built from the two 300 GB disks.

For the 1st tier of storage I plan to use a zpool that consists of a mirror vdev built from the two SSD disks.

For the 2nd tier I plan to use a zpool that consists of three 6-drive RAID-Z2 vdevs.

The two free slots leave me with some options should I want to change what I want to do with the OS+Application zpool and the 1st tier zpool.

Also, with the 3x6 zpool (2nd tier) I believe I would achieve the best possible outcome taking both available storage and fault-tolerance into account.

However, the questions really come up with the external direct-attached storage. Only the 1st tier (SSDs) are hit with constant writes of new logs coming in, and the tiers 2 and 3 only see logs transferred in and out once per day when the application checks for logs that exceed the retention set for the tier on which they current reside. **Would larger disks - say 4TB and even bigger - disks be an issue if the DAS would be built from RAID-Z2 vdevs? Or would it be better to go with mirror vdevs?** I have understood that resilvering would be less of a hassle with mirroring compared to RAIDZ-2.

For the DAS my options seem to be either Dell MD1420 or MD1400. The latter will give me more options with bigger (and slower/cheaper) disks, whereas the former would limit my choices to 2.5" disks. I guess in theory I could also have the option to with 3.5" disks in the server chassis itself if there is an option into where 12x3.5" disks + 4x2.5" disks can be fitted. Once again, the 2nd tier (with the SSDs being the 1st tier) would not see continuous writes nor reads but could still see reads quite often during working hours when logs older than 7 days need to be retrieved. However, I do not really possess the sufficient knowledge to make the decision whether something cheaper than 10K drives would suffice for this 2nd tier.

Comment: Why bother with tiered storage?  That just adds additional copying of data. Are you reading the data enough that tiered storage is needed?  The most efficient way to tier data is to replicate the input stream to all tiers when you ingest it, then delete it from each tier as it ages off.  Otherwise your intermediate tiers have to handle both twice the bandwidth and twice the IO ops as the data has to be copied over and over as it migrates from tier to tier.  With a lot of data, such extraneous copying is expensive.  **Never** copy data unless you have to.

Comment: The tiered storage concept is because of the application. Unfortunately, as long as I wish to have something on SSD while the rest is not, I need to do this kind of tiered storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Would larger disks - say 4TB and even bigger - disks be an issue if the DAS would be built from RAID-Z2 vdevs? Or would it be better to go with mirror vdevs?

The only reason for using mirror besides resilvering-time would be IOPS because these should scale with amount of disks in mirror setup and are equal to a single disk in RAIDZ.

I doubt this would matter here. You talk about 'retrieval' i.e. copying the data so it's mostly a sequential read workload. A few hundred milliseconds time to wait - in the worst case when hundreds of parallel accesses are waiting - should still be good enough. It's not a database server, it's more a less a NAS.

However if you have the hardware just run some tests.

Additionally if it's only logfiles be sure to switch on compression and maybe even consider raising the recordsize to 1mb for better compression if you have mostly sequential read/writes.